# Netsuite Data Information

Tags: netsuite, items, data-extraction, invoices

I am trying to integrate Netsuite and extract the data out of it. Need to establish a relation between Sales Orders, Items, and Invoices. Can anyone which objects store this information and how it's related?

Comment: RTFM first, then post a detailed question about specific needs. You will have a better chance of getting assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Record types of Netsuite are the following:

1. Entity - Customer, Employee, Partner, Vendor
2. Item - Products (holds product related details)
3. Transactions: SO, Invoice, Bill, Credit Memo, Return Auth, Rev Commit, Deposit, Cash Sales etc.

Relationship:
Customer -->SO <--- Item
SO --->Invoice -----> payment or refund

Please see the Netsuite schema browser for more detail
https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_1/schema/record/account.html